# Blank icon shows up on the taskbar even though I selected an icon

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, icons

I setup a shortcut on the taskbar to go directly to a specific Zoom meeting. Initially, it showed up with the standard Zoom icon.  But then it's been replaced with a blank space.

[image]

I've gone in and re-selected the icon, but nothing seems to help. I then picked a completely random icon, but that didn't work either. I've also logged out then back in - that didn't help either.

However, the icon does show up if I right-click on the shortcut:

[image]

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Thanks for the suggestion.  I just tried it but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I mean, I restarted the entire machine.  But yeah, I just restared explorer.exe as well, and it didn't help

Comment: bummer :( ... sorry I couldn't help with a simple fix.  Good luck!

Comment: How have you pinned the shortcut? Where is it located?

Comment: @harrymc Yes, it's pinned.  The shortcut is currently located on the desktop.  But it shouldn't matter because when you pin a shortcut, it moves to the `%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar` directory.  As evidenced by this screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/doBdbU0.png

Note that the icon for Zoom actually shows up in that view.

Comment: I suggest putting the command in a `.bat` file located on the desktop, setting its icon, and pinning this file.